# How to copy entire object in angularjs?

Tags: json, angularjs

being a newbie to angular got stuck in copying json data, I need to copy my entire json object to clipboard , and then paste it later on.
have done it through ngClip , but it dosen't copy the entire object else it copies the object name.below is what I've done so far:

```
<label>Copy #1</label>

<button class="btn btn-default" clip-copy="copy1">Copy!</button>
<script>
   var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ngClipboard"]);

   myapp.config(['ngClipProvider', function(ngClipProvider) {
      ngClipProvider.setPath("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.1.6/ZeroClipboard.swf");
   }]);

   myapp.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.copy1 = {};
      $scope.copy1.Name = "ABC";
      $scope.copy1.age = 24;
      $scope.copy1.City = "Pittsburgh";

   });
</script>
```

Clicking on Copy! button always copies copy1, I want it to copy the entire object.However if I give copy1.Name in clip-copy it copies ABC.
Any leads wud be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try converting the object into a json string before you put into copy1?

Comment: @Icycool : please see the edited one, it copies the name of the object, nothing else, tried with JSON.stringify also.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411754/should-i-use-angular-copy-or-clone

Comment: @Fissio: have seen this link, but I guess angular.copy or clone makes a copy of the object locally, I want it to be copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to convert your object to string. It will return you a string which you can copy on clip board.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because `copy1` is an object. Try using `angular.toJson()` to convert the object to a string. Like this:

```
<label>Copy #1</label>

<button class="btn btn-default" clip-copy="test()">Copy!</button>
<script>
   var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ngClipboard"]);

   myapp.config(['ngClipProvider', function(ngClipProvider) {
      ngClipProvider.setPath("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.1.6/ZeroClipboard.swf");
   }]);

   myapp.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.copy1 = {};
      $scope.copy1.Name = "ABC";
      $scope.copy1.age = 24;
      $scope.copy1.City = "Pittsburgh";

      $scope.test = function () {
        return angular.toJson($scope.copy1);
      }

   });
</script>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KISecLdBfOMxVPFT6MMZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use `angular.copy($scope.copy1,$scope.target)` . it will copy your entire copy1 object to target object.