# What's alternative to angular.copy in Angular

Tags: angular

How can I copy an object and lose its reference in Angular?

With AngularJS, I can use `angular.copy(object)`, but I'm getting some error using that in Angular.

> EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: `angular` is not defined

Comment: Check this solution it might help:
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41475939/4509214)

Comment: In many situations, you might want to use `.copy()` but actually wouldnt need it. In various AngJS1 projects I have seen, it was an overkill, where a manual copy of the relevant substructures would have made for a cleaner code. Maybe that was part of the decision not to implement it by the Angular team.

Comment: by the way, related (and also unanswered): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124528/one-way-binding-objects-in-angular-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 211):

Assuming you are using ES6, you can use `var copy = Object.assign({}, original)`. Works in modern browsers; if you need to support older browsers check out this [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)

**update:**

With TypeScript 2.1+, ES6 shorthand object spread notation is available:

```ts
const copy = { ...original }
```

Comment: Note that `angular.copy()` creates a deep copy contrary to `Object.assign()`. If you want deep copy use lodash `_.cloneDeep(value)` https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep

Comment: in Webstorm I got `Unresolved function or method assign()` ; IDE Details: Webstorm 2016.2. How can I resolve that ?

Comment: @meorfi Go to `File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript` and set `Javascript language version` to `ECMAScript 6.0`.

Comment: @bertrandg _.clone(value) is different than angular.copy(), it will not create new instance, so as _.cloneDeep(value) it still create a reference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411754/should-i-use-angular-copy-or-clone

Comment: The Typescript solution does not work. Although you create a copy of the object, you als wrap an object around the copy. I think you should remove that part from your answer.

Comment: @Michelangelo Not sure what you mean by `wrap object around copy`. They are the same - http://plnkr.co/edit/7jbdqqlFWdaSFLac9zhy?p=preview

Comment: @Sasxa Ok, you seem to be right but I got something like this: `{ { name: "Michelangelo" } }`...very odd. I am using Typescript from angular cli, will check my version.

Comment: @Sasxa Hmmm, ok I use TypeScript 2.0.3 so not the latest, I am sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Additionally, if you're copying an array, use: `const copy = [ ...original ]`

Comment: Neither {...object} or [...array] make any difference even when used together. Does this answer actually work?

Comment: WHY THIS answer shown almost at the bottom? It has most upvotes. **spread** operator works nice with nested properties as well. It is cool

Comment: Also note that if your original is `null` then `angular.copy(original)` will return `null` while this solution will return `{}`, which will behave differently if used in an `if` check or something.

Comment: ... spreading operator should not be used as an alternative to angular.copy, which is deep copy. You can probably use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xxx))

Comment: Object.assign is not an alternative for angular.copy,in fact, it only works for totally flat objects, otherwise it's probably always not what you are looking for.

Comment: Be careful! This answer is simply wrong.  spread notation has nothing to do with what angular.copy does. Strange why it has so many upvotes.

Answer (score 46):

Till we have a better solution, you can use the following:

```
duplicateObject = <YourObjType> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject));
```

**EDIT: Clarification**

Please note: The above solution was only meant to be a quick-fix one liner, provided at a time when Angular 2 was under active development. My hope was we might eventually get an equivalent of `angular.copy()`. Therefore I did not want to write or import a deep-cloning library.

This method also has issues with parsing date properties (it will become a string).

*Please do not use this method in production apps*. Use it only in your experimental projects - the ones you are doing for learning Angular 2.

Comment: this ruins your dates and is slow as hell.

Comment: @LanderV Agreed, this is slow as hell. My objective, though not stated explicitly, was to have a single line solution. This allows us to replace it with the equivalent of angular.copy() when it becomes available later.

Comment: Not as slow as importing an entire library to do a single task though, as long as what you're doing is pretty simple...

Comment: this is horrible, never use that

Comment: @MurhafSousli please try to understand the context of this answer. This was provided when Angular 2 was under development, and the hope was that we will eventually get an equivalent of angular.copy() function. To bridge the waiting period, I put out this solution as a temp option till we have a better solution. This is a one-liner with deep cloning. This is *horrible*, I agree... But given the experimental context at that time, it is not that bad.

Comment: @LeoCaseiro lodash.clonedeep is different thing. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411754/should-i-use-angular-copy-or-clone

Comment: @IanBelcher It _is_ slower than importing a library with a function. With ES6 module and tree-shaking, bundling, etc, you get just the function you use.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović of course in 2018 that is the case and I totally agree with you *today*, but in 2016 webpack didn't have tree shaking so you'd be importing an entire library in most cases.

Comment: Yikes I didn't even realize what year it was. Apologies for pinging!

Comment: If the object what you would like to copy contains getters, those will be lost during use JSON.parse(JSON.stingify(obj)).

Answer (score 37):

The alternative for deep copying objects having nested objects inside is by using lodash's cloneDeep method.

For Angular, you can do it like this:

Install lodash with `yarn add lodash` or `npm install lodash`.

In your component, import `cloneDeep` and use it:

```
import { cloneDeep } from "lodash";
...
clonedObject = cloneDeep(originalObject);
```

It's only 18kb added to your build, well worth for the benefits.

I've also written an [article here](http://blog.bogdancarpean.com/deepcopy-of-javascript-objects-and-arrays-using-lodashs-clonedeep-method), if you need more insight on why using lodash's cloneDeep.

Comment: "only 18kb" added to the output to just be able to deep copy objects? JavaScript is a mess.

Comment: After reading your referenced article, I understanf the `cloneDeep` method instantiates a new object. Should we still use it if we already have a destination object ?

Answer (score 19):

For **shallow** copying you could use Object.assign which is a ES6 feature

```
let x = { name: 'Marek', age: 20 };
let y = Object.assign({}, x);
x === y; //false
```

**DO NOT use it for deep cloning**

Comment: What can be used for deep cloning?

Comment: Why give this answer if it doesn't answer the question?! This answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 15):

Use lodash as bertandg indicated. The reason angular no longer has this method, is because angular 1 was a stand-alone framework, and external libraries often ran into issues with the angular execution context. Angular 2 does not have that problem, so use whatever library that you want.

https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution I've found is:

```
let yourDeepCopiedObject = _.cloneDeep(yourOriginalObject);
```

***IMPORTANT STEPS:** 
You must install lodash to use this (which was unclear from other answers):

```
$ npm install --save lodash

$ npm install --save @types/lodash
```

and then import it in your ts file:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

Comment: This creates a warning in Angular 10:
WARNING in /.../test.component.ts depends on 'lodash'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to copy a class instance, you can use Object.assign too, but you need to pass a new instance as a first parameter (instead of {}) :

```
class MyClass {
    public prop1: number;
    public prop2: number;

    public summonUnicorn(): void {
        alert('Unicorn !');
    }
}

let instance = new MyClass();
instance.prop1 = 12;
instance.prop2 = 42;

let wrongCopy = Object.assign({}, instance);
console.log(wrongCopy.prop1); // 12
console.log(wrongCopy.prop2); // 42
wrongCopy.summonUnicorn() // ERROR : undefined is not a function

let goodCopy = Object.assign(new MyClass(), instance);
console.log(goodCopy.prop1); // 12
console.log(goodCopy.prop2); // 42
goodCopy.summonUnicorn() // It works !
```

Comment: this is ectually what I need

Answer (score 7):

As others have already pointed out, using lodash or underscore is probably the best solution. But if you do not need those libraries for anything else, you can probably use something like this:

```
  function deepClone(obj) {

    // return value is input is not an Object or Array.
    if (typeof(obj) !== 'object' || obj === null) {
      return obj;    
    }

    let clone;

    if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
      clone = obj.slice();  // unlink Array reference.
    } else {
      clone = Object.assign({}, obj); // Unlink Object reference.
    }

    let keys = Object.keys(clone);

    for (let i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
      clone[keys[i]] = deepClone(clone[keys[i]]); // recursively unlink reference to nested objects.
    }

    return clone; // return unlinked clone.

  }
```

That's what we decided to do.

Comment: // to unlink dates we can add: if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Date]') 
        {
            return new Date(obj.getTime());
        }

Comment: or check date using instance type - if(obj instanceof Date){return new Date(obj.getTime())}

Answer (score 3):

```
let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

The `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string

Comment: This has already been said exhaustively above that this is the worst way to treat it!

Comment: @Alessandro: Care to explain your statement? 
Original question is not for any particular scenario. This can be used for many cases and may not be the best for some. This is just one of many ways to do it. Explain how this is the worst?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a service to use with Angular 5 or higher, it uses the `angular.copy()` the base of angularjs, it works well for me. Additionally, there are other functions like `isUndefined`, etc. I hope it helps.
Like any optimization, it would be nice to know. regards

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AngularService {

  private TYPED_ARRAY_REGEXP = /^\[object (?:Uint8|Uint8Clamped|Uint16|Uint32|Int8|Int16|Int32|Float32|Float64)Array\]$/;
  private stackSource = [];
  private stackDest = [];

  constructor() { }

  public isNumber(value: any): boolean {
    if ( typeof value === 'number' ) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
  }

  public isTypedArray(value: any) {
    return value && this.isNumber(value.length) && this.TYPED_ARRAY_REGEXP.test(toString.call(value));
  }

  public isArrayBuffer(obj: any) {
    return toString.call(obj) === '[object ArrayBuffer]';
  }

  public isUndefined(value: any) {return typeof value === 'undefined'; }

  public isObject(value: any) {  return value !== null && typeof value === 'object'; }

  public isBlankObject(value: any) {
    return value !== null && typeof value === 'object' && !Object.getPrototypeOf(value);
  }

  public isFunction(value: any) { return typeof value === 'function'; }

  public setHashKey(obj: any, h: any) {
    if (h) { obj.$$hashKey = h; }
    else { delete obj.$$hashKey; }
  }

  private isWindow(obj: any) { return obj && obj.window === obj; }

  private isScope(obj: any) { return obj && obj.$evalAsync && obj.$watch; }


  private copyRecurse(source: any, destination: any) {

    const h = destination.$$hashKey;

    if (Array.isArray(source)) {
      for (let i = 0, ii = source.length; i < ii; i++) {
        destination.push(this.copyElement(source[i]));
      }
    } else if (this.isBlankObject(source)) {
      for (const key of Object.keys(source)) {
        destination[key] = this.copyElement(source[key]);
      }
    } else if (source && typeof source.hasOwnProperty === 'function') {
      for (const key of Object.keys(source)) {
        destination[key] = this.copyElement(source[key]);
      }
    } else {
      for (const key of Object.keys(source)) {
        destination[key] = this.copyElement(source[key]);
      }
    }
    this.setHashKey(destination, h);
    return destination;
  }

  private copyElement(source: any) {

    if (!this.isObject(source)) {
      return source;
    }

    const index = this.stackSource.indexOf(source);

    if (index !== -1) {
      return this.stackDest[index];
    }

    if (this.isWindow(source) || this.isScope(source)) {
      throw console.log('Cant copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported.');
    }

    let needsRecurse = false;
    let destination = this.copyType(source);

    if (destination === undefined) {
      destination = Array.isArray(source) ? [] : Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(source));
      needsRecurse = true;
    }

    this.stackSource.push(source);
    this.stackDest.push(destination);

    return needsRecurse
      ? this.copyRecurse(source, destination)
      : destination;
  }

  private copyType = (source: any) => {

    switch (toString.call(source)) {
      case '[object Int8Array]':
      case '[object Int16Array]':
      case '[object Int32Array]':
      case '[object Float32Array]':
      case '[object Float64Array]':
      case '[object Uint8Array]':
      case '[object Uint8ClampedArray]':
      case '[object Uint16Array]':
      case '[object Uint32Array]':
        return new source.constructor(this.copyElement(source.buffer), source.byteOffset, source.length);

      case '[object ArrayBuffer]':
        if (!source.slice) {
          const copied = new ArrayBuffer(source.byteLength);
          new Uint8Array(copied).set(new Uint8Array(source));
          return copied;
        }
        return source.slice(0);

      case '[object Boolean]':
      case '[object Number]':
      case '[object String]':
      case '[object Date]':
        return new source.constructor(source.valueOf());

      case '[object RegExp]':
        const re = new RegExp(source.source, source.toString().match(/[^\/]*$/)[0]);
        re.lastIndex = source.lastIndex;
        return re;

      case '[object Blob]':
        return new source.constructor([source], {type: source.type});
    }

    if (this.isFunction(source.cloneNode)) {
      return source.cloneNode(true);
    }
  }

  public copy(source: any, destination?: any) {

    if (destination) {
      if (this.isTypedArray(destination) || this.isArrayBuffer(destination)) {
        throw console.log('Cant copy! TypedArray destination cannot be mutated.');
      }
      if (source === destination) {
        throw console.log('Cant copy! Source and destination are identical.');
      }

      if (Array.isArray(destination)) {
        destination.length = 0;
      } else {
        destination.forEach((value: any, key: any) => {
          if (key !== '$$hashKey') {
            delete destination[key];
          }
        });
      }

      this.stackSource.push(source);
      this.stackDest.push(destination);
      return this.copyRecurse(source, destination);
    }

    return this.copyElement(source);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can clone the Array like

```
 this.assignCustomerList = Object.assign([], this.customerList);
```

And clone the object like

```
this.assignCustomer = Object.assign({}, this.customer);
```

Comment: This is wrong since angularjs.copy supports deepCopy. Hence your answer is misleading since doesn't support deepClone of an object.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this feature just form my app 'models' (raw backend data converted to objects). So I ended up using a combination of [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) (create new object from specified prototype) and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (copy properties between objects). Need to handle the deep copy manually. I created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/mppfiles/85c7609d9eeb74e4b6e02f1b91157162) for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using an npm pacakage, you can try out *"ngx-scv-util"*:

Install the package by running following command:

```
npm i ngx-scv-util --save
```

Import the package into your component using:

```
import { NgxScvUtil } from "ngx-scv-util";
....
constructor(private util: NgxScvUtil) {}
```

Usage:

```
let newObject = this.util.deepCopy(originalObject);
```

It is a very light package. More information is available here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-scv-util

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Issue, and didn't wanna use any plugins just for deep cloning:

```
static deepClone(object): any {
        const cloneObj = (<any>object.constructor());
        const attributes = Object.keys(object);
        for (const attribute of attributes) {
            const property = object[attribute];

            if (typeof property === 'object') {
                cloneObj[attribute] = this.deepClone(property);
            } else {
                cloneObj[attribute] = property;
            }
        }
        return cloneObj;
    }
```

Credits: [I made this function more readable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152032/6270117), please check the exceptions to its functionality below

Answer (score 0):

I as well as you faced a problem of work angular.copy and angular.expect because they do not copy the object or create the object without adding some dependencies. My solution was this:

```
  copyFactory = (() ->
    resource = ->
      resource.__super__.constructor.apply this, arguments
      return
    this.extendTo resource
    resource
  ).call(factory)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already using lodash I wouldn't recommend installing it just for this one method. I suggest instead a more narrowly specialized library such as 'clone':

```
npm install clone
```