# Deep copy an array in Angular 2 + TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have an array of objects that is an input. Lets call it `content`.

When trying to deep copy it, it still has a reference to the previous array.

I need to duplicate that input array, and change one property of the duplicated part.

So long I've tried different methods that weren't successful.

ES6 way:

```
public duplicateArray() {
  arr = [...this.content]
  arr.map((x) => {x.status = DEFAULT});
  return this.content.concat(arr);
}
```

The `slice` way:

```
public duplicateArray() {
  arr = this.content.slice(0);
  arr.map((x) => {x.status = DEFAULT});
  return this.content.concat(arr);
}
```

In both of them all the objects inside the array have `status: 'Default'`.

What's the best approach to deep copy the array in Angular 2?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Check this:

```
  let cloned = source.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
```

Comment: if i'm not missing something this doesn't work for strings-- when I try
`var source = ["one","two","three"];
var cloned = source.map(x => Object.assign({},x));`

I end up with cloned as:
`[ { '0': 'o', '1': 'n', '2': 'e' },
  { '0': 't', '1': 'w', '2': 'o' },
  { '0': 't', '1': 'h', '2': 'r', '3': 'e', '4': 'e' } ]`

Comment: @ossec the Object.assign() method copies enumerable properties from a source object to a target object. String variable is an array-like object. Each character will be added as a new property to target object in cloned array.  Your example works correctly and here need additional check for strings in source array.

Comment: As for me `source.map(x => ({ ...x }));` suits the best.

Comment: Not compatible with internet explorer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: If you want to clone the array object, This option is more preferable.

Comment: After 2 hours of search. This worked! THANKS A TON!

Answer (score 58):

Simple:

```
let objCopy  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

This Also Works (Only for Arrays)

```
let objCopy2 = obj.slice()
```

Comment: may not be most efficient but definitely the easiest... and will work for any objects / arrays

Comment: This may be a good idea.  But there is a but: I do not think this copies methods, assuming the objects have methods.

Comment: We use this method in production, of which has 2 nested models in the main model, the call to get the models works perfectly and the getError() method works as well

Comment: Saved my day than Object.assign([], this.list); (line)

Comment: If the object has function properties or cyclic references this won't work.

Comment: JSON.stringify has a replace function `JSON.stringify(<object>, <replacer func>)` for handing cyclical and function properties

Comment: But this does not work for object methods in typescript

Answer (score 18):

This is `Daria`'s suggestion (see comment on the question) which works starting from [TypeScript 2.1](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/12/23/typescript-2-1-object-rest-and-spread) and basically [clones each element from the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688517/whats-alternative-to-angular-copy-in-angular):

```
this.clonedArray = theArray.map(e => ({ ... e }));
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you Alexei!! Very simple and elegant :)

Comment: Seems very quick too and no need to include additional lodash libraries.

Comment: I find this the only way that actually deep clones. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` works but converts integer values into strings.

Comment: @Abhi I have also relied on this for some cases such as when working with a rather big state in a reducer which must be cloned to ensure function purity.

Answer (score 16):

This is working for me:

```
this.listCopy = Object.assign([], this.list);
```

Comment: @makkasi That's not true. changing this.list after this.listCopy has been set, will not affect this.listCopy for sure!!

Comment: OK.May be I'm wrong. I tested with this code and it changes the other list. May be the reason is somewhere else. I don't have access to computer at the moment. Will try this later. I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @kabus, it will if `this.list` contains objects. If you modify any object contained in `this.list`, the changes will be reflected to `this.listCopy`, because it keeps just references.

Comment: @el.atomo can you provide an example, because i cant reproduce it

Comment: Sure @kabus, ```let list = [{a: 1}]; let listCopy = Object.assign([], list); list[0].a = 2; console.log(list[0].a, listCopy[0].a);```. Sorry for the ugly formatting :)

Comment: @el.atomo and makkasi lol you guys are right, it's not working anymore. I swear this worked before! :)

Comment: @kabus, it does work if the array contains primitives, but it doesn't for objects: `let list = [1, 2, 3]; let listCopy = Object.assign([], list); list[0] = null; console.log(list[0], listCopy[0]);`, for that you need to implement/use a deep copy or use the JSON trick (if there're no circular references).

Comment: Not compatible with internet explorer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Linter fixed this to `this.listCopy = { ...[], ...this.list }` for me, so I guess it is also ok.

Answer (score 13):

The only solution I've found (almost instantly after posting the question), is to loop through the array and use `Object.assign()`

Like this:

```
public duplicateArray() {
  let arr = [];
  this.content.forEach((x) => {
    arr.push(Object.assign({}, x));
  })
  arr.map((x) => {x.status = DEFAULT});
  return this.content.concat(arr);
}
```

I know this is not optimal. And I wonder if there's any better solutions.

Comment: Not compatible with internet explorer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 10):

A clean way of deep copying objects having nested objects inside is by using lodash's cloneDeep method.

For Angular, you can do it like this:

Install lodash with `yarn add lodash` or `npm install lodash`.

In your component, import `cloneDeep` and use it:

```
import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
...
clonedObject = cloneDeep(originalObject);
```

It's only 18kb added to your build, well worth for the benefits.

I've also written an [article here](http://blog.bogdancarpean.com/deepcopy-of-javascript-objects-and-arrays-using-lodashs-clonedeep-method), if you need more insight on why using lodash's cloneDeep.

Comment: Be aware, in case your originalObject is an array of objects, objects won't be deep copied, their reference will be copied.

Answer (score 10):

I found deep copy method in angular devkit, It's very normal, so... maybe you can just implement yourself or use that.

I prefer to use loadash, there a lot of objects and array operation methods that can use.

```
import { deepCopy } from '@angular-devkit/core/src/utils/object';

export class AppComponent {
  source = {
    ....
  }
  constructor() {
     const newObject = deepCopy(this.source);
  }
}
```

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.8
@angular/cli                      10.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.8
@schematics/angular               10.0.8
@schematics/update                0.1000.8
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.43.0
```

Comment: Awsome solution, thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own. Doesn't work for complex cases, but for a simple array of Objects, it's good enough.

```
  deepClone(oldArray: Object[]) {
    let newArray: any = [];
    oldArray.forEach((item) => {
      newArray.push(Object.assign({}, item));
    });
    return newArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the GitHub project [ts-deepcopy](https://github.com/ykdr2017/ts-deepcopy), which is also available on npm, to clone your object, or just include the code snippet below.

```ts
/**
 * Deep copy function for TypeScript.
 * @param T Generic type of target/copied value.
 * @param target Target value to be copied.
 * @see Source project, ts-deepcopy https://github.com/ykdr2017/ts-deepcopy
 * @see Code pen https://codepen.io/erikvullings/pen/ejyBYg
 */
export const deepCopy = <T>(target: T): T => {
  if (target === null) {
    return target;
  }
  if (target instanceof Date) {
    return new Date(target.getTime()) as any;
  }
  if (target instanceof Array) {
    const cp = [] as any[];
    (target as any[]).forEach((v) => { cp.push(v); });
    return cp.map((n: any) => deepCopy<any>(n)) as any;
  }
  if (typeof target === 'object' && target !== {}) {
    const cp = { ...(target as { [key: string]: any }) } as { [key: string]: any };
    Object.keys(cp).forEach(k => {
      cp[k] = deepCopy<any>(cp[k]);
    });
    return cp as T;
  }
  return target;
};
```

Comment: Be aware that it does not clone empy objects which may cause unwanted behavior (you can remove the 'target !== {}' to fix this)

Answer (score -3):

you can use use JQuery for deep copying :

```
var arr =[['abc'],['xyz']];
var newArr = $.extend(true, [], arr);
newArr.shift().shift();

console.log(arr); //arr still has [['abc'],['xyz']]
```