# Issues with model bindings on Forms with several *ngFor

Tags: angular, binding, angular2-forms, ngfor

I'm using a form where I have the following model repeated several times :

- I have a select where I can choose whatever type of `Bottle` I have.
- An Input where I can select the quantity of bottles for the selected type.

This pattern is repeated for 2 arrays of Bottle (the `Bottle` type is made of an `Id` and a `Name`) as followed :

- An Array of `orderedBottles` where the user can order some bottles.
- An Array of `returnedBottles` where the user can return some bottles.

I want to be able to choose whatever type of bottle and corresponding count on the submit, but I believe I'm missing something because the behavior is all messed up :

- the Inputs of the 2 arrays are linked one-another,
- When I change some options in the select, sometimes the other selects are updated which is not what I want (obviously)...

Here is a working example in a plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/1z6dN6?p=preview

---

Here is my **html** file (I'm using AngularMaterial 2) :

```
  <div fxLayout="row" style="max-width: 80%">

    <!-- ORDERED BOTTLES -->
    <div fxLayout="column" style="min-width: 50%">
      <div fxLayout="row" style="max-width: 100%" *ngFor="let bottle of orderedBottles; let i = index">
        <md-select class="select" placeholder="Select bottle type" name="orderedTypeSelect_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="orderedBottles[i].typeId">
          <md-option class="options" *ngFor="let type of orderedClonedArrayBottles" [value]="type.typeId">
            {{ type.name }}
          </md-option>
        </md-select>

        <md-input-container class="container">
          <input md-input type="number" name="orderedBottleInput_{{i}}" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="orderedBottles[i].count"
          step="1" min="0" max="99">
        </md-input-container>

        <button class="button-row" type="button" (click)="removeRow(i, 'order')">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- RETURNED BOTTLES -->
    <div fxLayout="column" style="min-width: 50%">
      <div fxLayout="row" style="max-width: 100%" *ngFor="let bottle of returnedBottles; let j = index">
        <md-select class="select" placeholder="Select bottle type" name="returnedTypeSelect_{{j}}" [(ngModel)]="returnedBottles[j].typeId">
          <md-option class="options" *ngFor="let typed of returnedClonedArrayBottles" [value]="typed.typeId">
            {{ typed.name }}
          </md-option>
        </md-select>

        <md-input-container class="container">
          <input md-input type="number" name="returnedBottleInput_{{j}}" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="returnedBottles[j].count"
          step="1" min="0" max="99">
        </md-input-container>

        <button class="button-row" type="button" (click)="removeRow(j, 'return')">-</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

To add some explanation, this is a child component that has a single Array of `Bottle` as `@Input()`, which I clone in 2 different arrays (`orderedClonedArrayBottles` and `returnedClonedArrayBottles`) so that my parent array isn't updated from the child updates.

I then display my bottles with the `orderedBottles` Array and the `returnedBottles` that get their values from the 2 cloned beforehand.

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
    // Get @Input data when it's ready
    if (changes.bottleArray) {
      // Cloning
      //this.orderedClonedArrayBottles = [...changes.bottleArray.currentValue];
      //this.returnedClonedArrayBottles = [...changes.bottleArray.currentValue];

      this.orderedClonedArrayBottles = Array.from(changes.bottleArray.currentValue as Bottle[]);
      this.returnedClonedArrayBottles = Array.from(changes.bottleArray.currentValue as Bottle[]);

      console.log(this.orderedClonedArrayBottles);
      console.log(this.returnedClonedArrayBottles);

      // Display first rows
      if (this.orderedClonedArrayBottles.length > 0) {
        this.orderedBottles.push(this.orderedClonedArrayBottles[0]);
      }
      if (this.returnedClonedArrayBottles.length > 0) {
        this.returnedBottles.push(this.returnedClonedArrayBottles[0]);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have no idea why this isn't working correctly, most probably because I don't manage the `*ngFor` as I should. I have seen posts about `trackBy` for `*ngFor` but I have no idea if that will help or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cloning the `bottleArray`. But in your case the bottle objects are not cloned. The same references are pushed in two arrays.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504310/deep-copy-an-array-in-angular-2-typescript).

You may have to use `Object.assign` for each bottle object.
If you have nested objects you will have to traverse the properties and copy.

Comment: Working flawlessly. Thanks a lot !

Comment: For anyone in need : I posted my own deepClone() method in the link in the Answer.