# How to copy object inside an object and change any of its value in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I am using angular 2 and in my typescript file I have an object like this.

chartData: any

chartData has result array and each result is channel array

so chartData.result[0].channels[4], this is what we get initally

I want to push result[0] into result[1] and change channels[0].id = "New" and I am trying like

this.chartData.result.push(this.chartData.result[0]);

this.chartData.result[1].channels[0].id = "New"

When I am doing this, it changes id of channels[0] of both result[0] and result[1], why is this happening when I am trying to change only result[1] object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep copy an array in Angular 2 + TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504310/deep-copy-an-array-in-angular-2-typescript)

Comment: I linked a duplicate, but this really has nothing to do with angular/typescript. It's how javascript works. For future reference (ha), you're looking for info on "javascript pass by reference"

Answer (score 0):

Because you are binding pushing same object with its reference to an array element.May be doing below will help.

```
 this.chartData.result.push(Object.assign({}, this.chartData.result[0]));
```

Comment: Its still the same issue !

Comment: can you replicate it on plunker?