# Angular2,Typescript:How to push array of objects into another array of objects with only a few fields of the object

Tags: arrays, angular, object, typescript, ionic2

I know how to operate on array of objects but never had the necessity to push one array data into another. I need to push an array of objects into another array with only 2 fields of the object. Right now my object format is somewhat like this

```
data: [{
        "name": "Btech",
        "courseid": "1",
        "courserating": 5,
        "points": "100",
        "type": "computers"
    },
   {
        "name": "BCom",
        "courseid": "2",
        "courserating": 5,
        "points": "100",
        "type": "computers"
    }];
```

I want to push this into another array but I want only courseid and name in the object. I've read that we need to initialise the object in the constructor, use slice() and a few other functions and then push but I don't know how can I do it for mine since I need to push one array data into another.Kindly someone help me in this regard.

Comment: Supposing `other` is the other array, you can do it: `data.map(item => { return { courseid: item.courseid, name: item.name } }).forEach(item => other.push(item));`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're looking for the [array `map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const newArray = array.map(o => {
  return { name: o.name, courseid: o.courseid };
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
let data = [{
    "name": "Btech",
    "courseid": "1",
    "courserating": 5,
    "points": "100",
    "type": "computers"
},
{
    "name": "BCom",
    "courseid": "2",
    "courserating": 5,
    "points": "100",
    "type": "computers"
}];

let other = []; // your other array...

data.map(item => {
    return {
        courseid: item.courseid,
        name: item.name
    }
}).forEach(item => other.push(item));

console.log(JSON.stringify(other))
// => [{"courseid":"1","name":"Btech"},{"courseid":"2","name":"BCom"}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.Could you tell me how can deepcopy or clone an array in typescript ?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do it like this.

```
//assign your array of object to variable

var youArray:Array<any>= [{
    "name": "Btech",
    "courseid": "1",
    "courserating": 5,
    "points": "100",
    "type": "computers"
},
{
    "name": "BCom",
    "courseid": "2",
    "courserating": 5,
    "points": "100",
    "type": "computers"
}];

var resultArray:Array<any>=[] //empty array which we are going to push our selected items, always define types 

youArray.forEach(i=>{ 
   resultArray.push(
   {
    "name":i.name,
    "courseid":i.courseid
   });
});

console.log(resultArray)
```

if you still have doubts about this.please follow this [url](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_push.htm)

Comment: Could you tell me how to deepcopy or clone an array in typescript ?

Comment: @Impromptu_Coder did u see this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504310/deep-copy-an-array-in-angular-2-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Map to a returning JSON data, subscribe it to an existing array or an empty one. #typescript

```
  let pictimeline= []; 
    var timeline = this.picService.fetchtimeline(this.limit)


.map((data : Response) => data.json())
    .subscribe(pictimeline=> this.pictimeline = pictimeline);


console.log(this.pictimeline);
```