# Deep copy, children still refer to original object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, clone, deep-copy

I have a problem with deep copy/clone on a object (TypeScript,Angular4,Ionic3) that also holds a list of other objects. Whenever I change the child objects in the copy, the original is also inflicted by the change and vice versa. My REST API gives me the following JSON back:

[image]

I have 2 types of objects that are relevant in this case, there are more but they do not need to be changed, therefore I do not include those:

```
import { Declaration } from './declaration.entity';

export class Period{
    constructor(
        public number: number,
        public status: string,
        public year: number,
        public month: number,
        public sum: number,
        public orderNumber: string,
        public userId: string,
        public submitDate: Date,
        public comment: string,
        public declarations: Declaration[]
    ){}
}
```

And

```
import { FileCustom } from './file.entity';
import { Period } from './period.entity';

export class Declaration{
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public status: string,
        public name: string,
        public description: string,
        public amount: number,
        public date: Date,
        public period: Period,
        public userId: string,
        public files: FileCustom[],
        public comment: string   
    ){}
}
```

I want to change the field of a Declaration that is inside a Period. I have a object called periods (list of periods), which I want to clone. I need periods to be untouched. I looked at some other topics with possible solutions and tried them:

```
let cloned = this.periods.map(x => Object.assign({},x));
```

And

```
let cloned = this.periods.map(x => Object.assign([],x));
```

From this topic:

[Deep copy an array in Angular 2 + TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504310/deep-copy-an-array-in-angular-2-typescript)

When I use one of the above solutions and change for example the comment field of the **period** in the copy, the original file remains untouched. But when I change the comment field of the **declaration** inside the period, the original file is also changed, which is what I want to prevent. How can I deep copy/clone my list of periods without any children having **any** references to the original?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Object.assign` doesn't do a full deep copy by itself it just copies properties from one object to the other. If those properties contain other objects those references are going to be maintained. You probably wanted to look at [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object prototypes aren't an issue and objects don't contain functions you could `JSON.stringify()`  and parse that back to new object

```
let cloned = this.periods.map(x => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)));
```

Or stringify whole `this.periods` at one time

```
let cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.periods))
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your first solution and that worked for me. I'll mark this answer as the solution, however, I still don't fully comprehend. I will read through the topic marked as a duplicate (by Patrick & toskv) to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with lodash's `cloneDeep` function to avoid stringifying the objects back and forth.

For your Angular project, you can do it like this:

Install `lodash` with `yarn add lodash` or `npm install lodash`

Since we are going to use only the `cloneDeep` function, in order to reduce the bundle, we are going to only import the function into the component, not the whole `lodash` library:

`import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';`

The, we are going to use it like this to deep copy the objects:

`copiedList = cloneDeep(originalList);`

Now changing something into an object nested in the copy will not change the original object.

This solution will add 18 kb to your production Angular bundle.