# Deep copying objects in Angular

Tags: angular

AngularJS has `angular.copy()` to deep copy objects and arrays.

Does Angular also have something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i use angular.copy in angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688517/how-can-i-use-angular-copy-in-angular-2)

Comment: `Duplicate` maybe, but i wanted a `non-polyfill` solution. just like `angular.copy()`

Comment: That's all we've got.

Comment: So, no `angular.copy()` hmm. Should I delete the question ?

Comment: I guess so. Doesn't seem to provide much value to keep it, because there is also a quite similar question.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can also use:

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object))`

if it's on your scope, it's in every Angular component, directive, etc. and it's also on every node environment.

Unless you have a circular reference, it should work and will effectively dissociate your variable reference to the original object.

Comment: This seems like a very simple and effective deep copy!  Why is this not scoring higher?  Is something wrong with this answer?

Comment: For a deep copying solution that will remove all references this is the best method, available on Browser/CommonJS, etc. I use it in production when an object snapshot is needed. I guess I arrived to answer a little late, like 1 year too late. @TSG

Comment: Also, if you're using an object literal with functions on it (not just values) they will be left out, but you can easily combine `Object.assing({}, oldObject, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObject)))` and this will repopulate your function properties from your object literal and with JSON will create a deep copy without any relation to original.

Comment: Best answer in my opinion

Comment: Beware, however, that this doesn't work when there are some Dates.

Comment: @FrantišekŽiačik Dates would be formatted as JSON types, which is the similar behavior you get when receiving a Rest response.
 
As a basic behavior it's simple and zero dependency, for a more complete solution it'd be advisable to complement this as a factory function to recover JSON date strings back to date objects.
It's a matter of *adapt to needs* instead of *one size fits all*  :)

Comment: It is not working with object of array

Answer (score 23):

Another option is to implement your own function:

```ts
/**
 * Returns a deep copy of the object
 */
public static deepCopy(oldObj: any) {
    var newObj = oldObj;
    if (oldObj && typeof oldObj === "object") {
        if (oldObj instanceof Date) {
           return new Date(oldObj.getTime());
        }
        newObj = Object.prototype.toString.call(oldObj) === "[object Array]" ? [] : {};
        for (var i in oldObj) {
            newObj[i] = this.deepCopy(oldObj[i]);
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

Comment: I am not able to deep copy dates using this method

Comment: I've added clone of Date based on [How to clone a Date object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090817/387194)

Answer (score 22):

This question isn't a duplicate of [How can I use angular.copy in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688517/how-can-i-use-angular-copy-in-angular-2) because the OP is asking about deep copying objects. The linked answer recommends [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which doesn't make a deep copy.

Actually, using Angular2 doesn't restrict you from using other libraries like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) for deep copying objects with their [$.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function or [lodash](https://lodash.com/) with [_.cloneDeep()](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep).

The most common libraries have their typings available via [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) CLI tools so even when transpiling from TypeScript you can seamlessly use anything you want.

Also see: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Object.assign() doesn't do deep copy when there are nested objects within the targeted object, so as a naive solution you may go through the targeted object and do Object.assign() for every property of it!  
It worked for me when I didn't want to have a dependency on any third-party library

Answer (score 22):

You can `deep copy` an object in Angular by using lodash's cloneDeep method:

Install lodash with `yarn add lodash` or `npm install lodash`.

In your component, import `cloneDeep` and use it:

```
import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
...
clonedObject = cloneDeep(originalObject);
```

It's only 18kb added to your build, well worth for the benefits.

I've also written an [article here](http://blog.bogdancarpean.com/deepcopy-of-javascript-objects-and-arrays-using-lodashs-clonedeep-method), if you need more insight on why using lodash's cloneDeep.

Comment: the copying by value didn't work for me using Lodash. Do you maybe know why? I am still getting referenced values, so they both change at the same time, if I change one.

Answer (score 7):

```
Create helper class with name deepCopy.ts

/*
* DeepCopy class helps to copy an Original Array or an Object without impacting on original data
*/

export class DeepCopy {

  static copy(data: any) {
    let node;
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      node = data.length > 0 ? data.slice(0) : [];
      node.forEach((e, i) => {
        if (
          (typeof e === 'object' && e !== {}) ||
          (Array.isArray(e) && e.length > 0)
        ) {
          node[i] = DeepCopy.copy(e);
        }
      });
    } else if (data && typeof data === 'object') {
      node = data instanceof Date ? data : Object.assign({}, data);
      Object.keys(node).forEach((key) => {
        if (
          (typeof node[key] === 'object' && node[key] !== {}) ||
          (Array.isArray(node[key]) && node[key].length > 0)
        ) {
          node[key] = DeepCopy.copy(node[key]);
        }
      });
    } else {
      node = data;
    }
    return node;
  }
}
```

Import deepCopy file where ever you required and use as below code
 **DeepCopy.copy(arg);**  , Here arg would either object or array which you want

Comment: This actually the best answer. It effectively deep copies data without importing external libraries. I don't want to bring in a whole library to only use one function (even if it's only 18KB).

Comment: The best answer is this..! Awosome!!

Comment: I wouldn't blindly copy this snippet. It works, but with flaws. Within the array and the object assertion there is duplicate code. Within that duplicate code this `e!=={}` will always be true, and since `typeof [] === 'object'`, the part after the OR-pipes will never work as intended. This will also simply copy any dates it encounters. The first part of that ternary would be better looking like `? new Date(data) :`.

Answer (score 5):

Some modifications for [KrishnamrajuK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53222303/2110496)

```
export class DeepCopy {
  static copy(data: any, objMap?: WeakMap<any, any>) {
    if (!objMap) {
      // Map for handle recursive objects
      objMap = new WeakMap();
    }

    // recursion wrapper
    const deeper = value => {
      if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
        return DeepCopy.copy(value, objMap);
      }
      return value;
    };

    // Array value
    if (Array.isArray(data)) return data.map(deeper);

    // Object value
    if (data && typeof data === 'object') {
      // Same object seen earlier
      if (objMap.has(data)) return objMap.get(data);
      // Date object
      if (data instanceof Date) {
        const result = new Date(data.valueOf());
        objMap.set(data, result);
        return result;
      }
      // Use original prototype
      const node = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(data));
      // Save object to map before recursion
      objMap.set(data, node);
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        node[key] = deeper(value);
      }
      return node;
    }
    // Scalar value
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer deals with recursive objects which makes it the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

If the source is **an array of objects**, using map:

```
let cloned = source.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
```

OR

```
let cloned = source.map((x) => {
                return { ...x };
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers here rely on `lodash` which can cause issues when imported in angular 10+ with a warning message like the following:

```
WARNING in xxxxx.ts depends on lodash/cloneDeep. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
```

Other answers use parsing via JSON or try to roll their own implementation. Not to roll ours, we use `clone`: a lightweight clone utility with limited dependencies.

In order to use `clone`, you just need to install these two packages:

```sh
npm install clone
npm install --save-dev @types/clone
```

The create a service (the service is not mandatory, but I prefer this approach) that uses the clone API:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as clone from 'clone';

@Injectable()
export class ObjectCloneService {
    public cloneObject<T>(value: T): T {
        return clone<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Remember to add the service to your module.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a very simple function in typescript which accepts all possible inputs and gives the deep cloned copy of that object.

Hope it will help somebody.

```
  public deepCopy(obj) {

    var clonedObject: any;

    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        var itemArray = Object.assign([], obj);
        clonedObject = itemArray;

        for (var j = 0; j < clonedObject.length; j++) {
            clonedObject[j] = this.deepCopy(clonedObject[j]);
        }

        return clonedObject;
    }
    else if (typeof obj === 'number' || typeof obj == 'string') {
        return obj
    }
    else {


        var item = Object.assign({}, obj);
        clonedObject = item;

        let allKeys = Object.keys(clonedObject);

        for (var i = 0; i < allKeys.length; i++) {
            if (clonedObject[allKeys[i]] instanceof Array) {
                //If the calue is Array
                clonedObject[allKeys[i]] = this.deepCopy(clonedObject[allKeys[i]]);
            }
            else if (clonedObject[allKeys[i]] instanceof Date) {
                clonedObject[allKeys[i]] = new Date(clonedObject[allKeys[i]].valueOf());
            }
            else if (clonedObject[allKeys[i]] instanceof Object){
                //if the value is JOBJECT.
                clonedObject[allKeys[i]] = this.deepCopy(clonedObject[allKeys[i]]);
            }
        }
        return clonedObject;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am faced with the problem of deep copying. angular.copy({}, factory) and angular.extend({}, factory) helps well for array or hashes objects, but when copying an object a calass, sometimes there may be problems with connected dependencies. I solved this problem so:

```
 copyFactory = (() ->
    resource = ->
      resource.__super__.constructor.apply this, arguments
      return
    this.extendTo resource
    resource
  ).call(factory)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-scv-util

I faced the same issue and created an npm package for the same. I know its an overhead just for this functionality :) . I plan to add more to this package over time. This one has been tested on 10.1.6 version of Angular. It should definitely work with versions higher than 10.1.6. Usage details are mentioned on the npm package page.

Answer (score 0):

To use cloneDeep without any "CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.", you can use it like this:

```
npm i lodash-es --save
```

Then simply in any component:

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash-es';
// ...
let a = cloneDeep(b);
```