# Object assign deep copying cause trouble

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object array which I transform before submitting it to the controller.

Angular code to copy as follows:

```
    sourceObjArray: SourceObject[] = [..];
    targetObjArray: SourceObject[]= [];
    targetObjArray = object.assign(sourceObjArray);
   // when i change target object it also cause source object to change
    transformSourceObject(targetObjArray)
```

The following seems to be working:

```
targetObjArray = object.assign({}, sourceObjArray);
// when i call transform it does not effect source object :)
transformSourceObject(targetObjArray)
```

but it causes a the following problem.

```
Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@302753d0; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@302753d0; line: 1, column: 1]
```

My controller method signature is:

```
@RequestMapping(.., method=RequestMethod.POST)
public save(@RequestBody List<Object>, BindResult bindResult){}
```

Comment: Why do you think that's a copy? [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) mutates its first argument.

Comment: i simply want to do as in angular1 angular.copy which deep copy the object. can you suggest ?

Comment: Please add the code for `SourceObject` to the question

Comment: I'd suggest research! http://stackoverflow.com/q/36124363/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/34688517/3001761, ...

Comment: thanks for help got the ans from your post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i use angular.copy in angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688517/how-can-i-use-angular-copy-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with reference to the following post, found following code snippet working

[How can i use angular.copy in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688517/how-can-i-use-angular-copy-in-angular-2)

```
duplicateObject = <YourObjType> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject));
```

Comment: Then you should mark this post as a duplicate rather than copy over the answer. This is basic SO stuff for a 20k+ user!