# Angular let is referencing values from when previously declared?

Tags: angular, service

I pass an object to a service, changing a property and passing it back. I expected 'tempcard' and 'card' to hold different values after being changed by the service, but they are identical. I confirmed that the service is changing the value. What am I missing?

output:

> new call
>
> card (22925)moved:  ---before service
>
> 79 to 79
>
> card (22925)moved:  ---after service
>
> 25 to 25

expected:

> card (22925)moved:  ---before service
>
> 79 to 79
>
> card (22925)moved:  ---after service
>
> **79** to 25

code:

```
    //card is an object with the board1LaneId set to 79
    console.log('new call')
    let chs = new CardHelperService(card, this.flatTypes, this.auth);
    let tempcard = card;
    console.log('card (' + tempcard.id + ')moved: \n' +
        tempcard.board1LaneId + ' to ' + card.board1LaneId + '\n')

    card = chs.moveLane(dest); //call to my service 

    console.log('card (' + tempcard.id + ')moved: \n' +
          tempcard.board1LaneId + ' to ' + card.board1LaneId + '\n')
```

service code:

```
moveLane(dest:string){
   this.card.board1LaneId=25
   return this.card
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect that? `tempcard` and `card` are the same referenced object. Did you perhaps mean to _clone_ card into tempcard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm go with @Vaughan Hilts answer, but you want to fix simply update line 3 like below

```
let tempcard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(card));
```

let me know if anything wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You need a deep copy of `tempcard`

For example, something like:

```
let tempcard = clone(card);
```

... where clone is your choice of arbitrary `clone` function

You should read up on deep cloning here: [Deep copying objects in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36124363/deep-copying-objects-in-angular)

You should note that a shallow copy *might* be fine but if you have nested properties, you run into the same issue.