# Angular 17 changes not detected as expected

Tags: angular

I have this issue in a fairly complex web appp. I have tried to recreate it in simple form to share here but I can't so I assume its something specific to my build and probably won't get an answer but I'm posting because I've been at this for two days now and I'm getting desperate.

I have a service that defines an array. The service is injected into a component and I bind the display to that array

```
@for(item of myService.myArr; track $index;){
   <div>{{item}}</div>
}
```

Other components also have the service injected and they later call a method of it that adds a new item to the array using a simple `Array.push()`. The array is definitely updated but when this happens it doesn't seem to trigger change detection and my display is not update to show the newly added item.

If I then do anything else within the app, like perform some other interaction like clicking a button, then the view updates and I see the newly added items.
I can also get it to work by using `.detectChanges()` but this seems hacky as this issue is happening basically everywhere I have bound data so my code is absolutely full of `.detectChages()` which suggests a deeper issue right?

I have tried using `signal` to do this but the same issue arises.

So is there some issue with binding a view to an array stored in a service?
Is there some detail of change detection or data binding that I'm that I'm missing or misunderstanding?

Any help and suggestions would be great. Thanks all.

Comment: Is your component (or one of its parents) using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`? AFAIK the default change detection mode would pick up changes to elements of an array, but `OnPush` only detects changes after a "push", and updating a nested property [does not usually count](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/deep-dive-into-the-onpush-change-detection-strategy-in-angular-fab5e4da1d69).

Comment: The only change detection I'm doing manually is `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` and this only had to start happening after I did a big refactor and moved a load of logic from components into services - so I assume this is something I've done but am really struggling to understand even what the issue is, let alone how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are treated as objects. The `typeof` operator in JavaScript returns `object` for arrays.

In order for Angular to recognize the change, you need to change the object reference. (It is also the same with Signals. There used to be a function but it was dropped, here is [the explanation](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/c7ff9dff2c14aba70e92b9e216a2d4d97d6ef71e) )

For simple arrays you can use the spread operator `array = [...array]` for nested arrays `array = structuredClone(array)`.With the copy you get a different object reference and Angular change detection runs.

Further copying methods can be found in the answers to this question: [Deep copying objects in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36124363/deep-copying-objects-in-angular)

Comment: This is interesting. So how come if I have a basic array of numbers in a component, I bind that array to a list in the view and have a button that pushes to the array on click - then this works? Is this Angular being clever enough to understand the simpler setup?
I'll have a play around with what you suggest in the next couple of days and get back to you. It sounds like it may be the place to look.

Comment: This works when you use *ngFor. [Why this works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42962601/17038313)

Answer (score 0):

you should be using the change detector ref and listen for SimpleChanges.

```
private cdr = inject(ChangeDetectorRef);

ngOnInit(){this.cdr.detectChanges()}

ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){
if(changes['YOURARRAY']{
// update your array
}
}
```

https://angular.io/?search=17+change+detector