# angular2: how to copy object into another object

Tags: angular, typescript

Please help me in order to copy the object into another object using angular 2?

In angular, I used angular.copy() to copy objects to the loose reference of the old objects. But, when I used the same in angular 2 getting below error:

> Error: angular is not defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use angular.copy in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688517/how-can-i-use-angular-copy-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 192, accepted):

**Solution**

Angular2 developed on the ground of modern technologies like TypeScript and ES6.

So you can just do `let copy = Object.assign({}, myObject)`.

[Object assign](https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/immutable/javascript-solutions/object_assign) - nice  examples.

**For nested objects** :
`let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject))`

Comment: this won't work for nested objects. How can we deep copy nested objects?

Comment: This would copy an object by reference. What if I do want to copy by reference, so as to avoid any changes in myObject affecting 'copy' object.

Comment: @PratapA.K Take a look at loadsh, if you can load another library in your system. It  has functions such as _cloneDeep.

Comment: 'Object' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.ts(2702)

Answer (score 61):

```
let copy = Object.assign({}, myObject).  as mentioned above
```

but this wont work for nested objects. So an alternative would be

```
let copy =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject))
```

Comment: worked for me when nested objects are there, Thank you

Answer (score 14):

As suggested before, the clean way of deep copying objects having nested objects inside is by using lodash's cloneDeep method.

For Angular, you can do it like this:

Install lodash with `yarn add lodash` or `npm install lodash`.

In your component, import `cloneDeep` and use it:

```
import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
...
clonedObject = cloneDeep(originalObject);
```

It's only 18kb added to your build, well worth for the benefits.

I've also written an [article here](http://blog.bogdancarpean.com/deepcopy-of-javascript-objects-and-arrays-using-lodashs-clonedeep-method), if you need more insight on why using lodash's cloneDeep.

Comment: That works for me! Thank you :) It seems incredible that high level programming language cannot deal with a "copy" without reference...

Answer (score 11):

You can do in this in Angular with ECMAScript6 by using the spread operator:

```
let copy = {...myObject};
```

Comment: Downvoted because copy will hold a reference to the old object.

Answer (score 5):

```
let course = {
  name: 'Angular',
};

let newCourse= Object.assign({}, course);

newCourse.name= 'React';

console.log(course.name); // writes Angular
console.log(newCourse.name); // writes React
```

For Nested Object we can use of 3rd party libraries, for deep copying objects.
In case of lodash, use _.cloneDeep()

```
let newCourse= _.cloneDeep(course);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

Copy an Array :

```
const myCopiedArray  = Object.assign([], myArray);
```

Copy an object :

```
const myCopiedObject = Object.assign({}, myObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

Loadsh is the universal standard library for coping any object deepcopy. It's a recursive algorithm. It's check everything and does copy for the given object. Writing this kind of algorithm will take longer time. It's better to leverage the same.

Answer (score 2):

Object.assign will only work in single level of object reference.

To do a copy in any depth use as below:

```
let x = {'a':'a','b':{'c':'c'}};
let y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
```

If want to use any library instead then go with the `loadash.js` library.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do deep copy without any external library as below:

```
let originalObj = {'a':'a','b':{'c':'c'}};
let copyObj = structuredClone(originalObj);
```

[Complete Reference MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)

Answer (score 0):

thank you Saif from above. I tried his suggestion and it worked like a charm after I tried for three days to get my code to work.

```
  this.sElectionFinal.subscribe((election) => {
 const electionCopy = Object.assign({},election)
  this.electionsFinal.push(electionCopy)})
```