# Modifying an Javascript object copy makes the original object to change in Angular 5 Reactive Forms

Tags: javascript, angular5, javascript-objects, angular-reactive-forms, spread-syntax

I'm trying to create a copy of my reactive form value object (with spread operator or Object.assign) and apply some changes to it before sending it to my server.

This is the code that builds up my form, and it works as expected in my template:

```
newTask: FormGroup

this.newTask = this.formBuilder.group({
      partner:              [null, [Validators.required]],
      title:                [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      description:          [null, [Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(120)]],
      responsible:          [null, [Validators.required]],
      type:                 [null, [Validators.required]],
      priority:             [null, [Validators.required]],
      status:               [null, [Validators.required]],
      history:              this.formBuilder.array([])
    })
```

The code below illustrates how I can add and remove elements from my history array:

```
createAction (action?) {
    return this.formBuilder.group({

      title: [action ? action.title : undefined, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      description: [action ? action.description : undefined, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(200)]],
      resolveAt: [action ? action.resolveAt : undefined],
      result: [action ? action.response : undefined, [Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(200)]],
      resolvedAt: [action ? action.resolvedAt : undefined],
      status: [action ? action.status : undefined, [Validators.required]],
      relatedPerson: [action ? action.relatedPerson : undefined]

    })
  }

  addAction (action?): void {
    const history = this.newTask.get('history') as FormArray
    history.push(this.createAction(action || initialActionState))
  }

  removeAction (i: number): void {
    const history = this.newTask.get('history') as FormArray
    history.removeAt(i)
  }
```

After the user input all needed data correctly, when I submit my form this is the modification that I have to perform:

```
let cleanVar = {...this.newTask.value}
// I could also use let cleanVar = Object.assing({}, this.newTask.value), the result is the same
    cleanVar.history.forEach(item => {
      item.status = item.status.string
      if (item.relatedPerson) item.relatedPerson = item.relatedPerson._id
    })
console.log(this.newTask.value)
```

As you can see I'm trying to modify the copy of the original object, but when I log this.newTask.value, the changes propagated to it too.

I've never had any problem like this before with object copies, so I'm trying to find out why is this happening. Maybe it's something related to Angular Reactive Forms that I'm not being able to detect.

Does someone know why is this happening?

Thanks!

**Update**

This is what is inside my newTask.value variable:

[image]

Comment: There is no copy. In this line `let cleanVar = {...this.newTask.value}` cleanVar becomes a reference to an object literal but that in turn has (references to) the 'original' elements from `newTask.value`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how could I create a copy of my object? I thought the spread operator and Object.assign create copies without references... And in other cases I was able to achieve this, only when I try to copy the value of a reactive form this happens.

Comment: Can you share what's inside `newTask.value`?

Comment: Sure, it's in the updated version of my question.

Comment: If you have access to lodash library in your project, you can simply use `_.cloneDeep(objectToClone)` which will return you new copy. lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's alternative to angular.copy in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688517/whats-alternative-to-angular-copy-in-angular)

Comment: Cloning arrays in JS is tricky. If all elements are primitive values, you can achieve it with splice() but object elements will still be references then. Lodash is a good choice as it will take care of objects too.

Comment: Amazing, tried it and worked just fine! Thank you very much, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

As marekful and Rikin suggested, using lodash cloneDeep is the way to go:

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'

let clonedVar = cloneDeep (originalVar)

// do whatever you need with clonedVar and originalVar isn't touched
```

Thanks everyone!