# Use [(ngModel)] to change only the reference object, not the source

Tags: angular

I'm using `Angular 12.0.4`.

My template has an Input like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="end.itemOne">
<button (click)="resetField()">reset</button>


<p>why does <strong style="color:red">this.start</strong> change with input value? </p>
<strong>{{ this.start.itemOne }}</strong>
<br>
<br>
<p>I need only <strong style="color:blue">this.end</strong> to change </p>
<strong>{{ this.end.itemOne }}</strong>
```

Inside the component:

```
start: any = {
    itemOne: 'item1',
    itemTwo: 'item2'
  };

  end!: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.end = this.start;
  }

  resetField(): void {
    this.end = this.start;
  }
```

Here is a `stackblitz` showing the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njppqj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

My problem is: If I change the input value and then click on the `reset button` I want `this.end.itemOne` value to become 'item1' again. Instead, when I change the input value, both `this.start` and `this.end` become equal in value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ngOnInit(){this.resetField();}` `resetField():void{ this.end = {...this.start}}`. the whole point is to create copy of an object and put it into end. in your case start and end are referencing the same "pace in memory"

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how do I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: @gustavo-branco Object assignment by default is reference type you need to lose reference with some options that I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are looking for is `copy an object and lose its reference`. So you have [multiple option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688517/whats-alternative-to-angular-copy-in-angular) to achieve that.

Simplest way is spread notation:

```
this.end = {... this.start};
```

Another way is `Object.assign`

And for nested object you can even use:

```
<YourObjType> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sftvoi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I never saw this before, thank you! I used this 'spread notation' way.

Comment: the 'spread notation way' only works the first time the reset function runs, pressing the button a second time and the original problem comes back. Using JSON.parse solved the problem though.