# Chart.js: how do I group labels in toolips?

Tags: angular, d3.js, chart.js, ng2-charts, ng2-nvd3

I'm migrating a project from [ng2-nvd3](https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3) (based on D3) to [ng2-charts](http://valor-software.github.io/ng2-charts/) (based on Chart.js) because ng2-nvd3 is no longer maintained.

My app has a blood pressure chart that shows both systolic and diastolic entries. With ng2-nvd3, both values are grouped together in the tooltip. Also, the dates rendered have a bit more spacing in them. Here's a screenshot of what it looks like.

[image: ng2-nvd3 graph]

Here's the code to map the data to something the UI can understand:

```js
// Get blood pressure readings for the last 30 days
this.bloodPressureService.last30Days().subscribe((bpReadings: any) => {
    bpReadings = bpReadings.body;
    this.bpReadings = bpReadings;
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/34694155/65681
    this.bpOptions = { ...D3ChartService.getChartConfig() };
    if (bpReadings.readings.length) {
        this.bpOptions.title.text = bpReadings.period;
        this.bpOptions.chart.yAxis.axisLabel = 'Blood Pressure';
        let systolics, diastolics, upperValues, lowerValues;
        systolics = [];
        diastolics = [];
        upperValues = [];
        lowerValues = [];
        bpReadings.readings.forEach(item => {
            systolics.push({
                x: new Date(item.timestamp),
                y: item.systolic
            });
            diastolics.push({
                x: new Date(item.timestamp),
                y: item.diastolic
            });
            upperValues.push(item.systolic);
            lowerValues.push(item.diastolic);
        });
        this.bpData = [
            {
                values: systolics,
                key: 'Systolic',
                color: '#673ab7'
            },
            {
                values: diastolics,
                key: 'Diastolic',
                color: '#03a9f4'
            }
        ];
        // set y scale to be 10 more than max and min
        this.bpOptions.chart.yDomain = [Math.min.apply(Math, lowerValues) - 10, Math.max.apply(Math, upperValues) + 10];
    } else {
        this.bpReadings.readings = [];
    }
});
```

The `D3ChartService` is defined as follows:

```js
declare const d3, nv: any;

/**
 * ChartService to define the chart config for D3
 */
export class D3ChartService {

    static getChartConfig() {
        const today = new Date();
        const priorDate = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() - 30);
        return {
            chart: {
                type: 'lineChart',
                height: 200,
                margin: {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 40,
                    left: 55
                },
                x(d) {
                    return d.x;
                },
                y(d) {
                    return d.y;
                },
                useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                dispatch: {},
                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Dates',
                    showMaxMin: false,
                    tickFormat(d) {
                        return d3.time.format('%b %d')(new Date(d));
                    }
                },
                xDomain: [priorDate, today],
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: '',
                    axisLabelDistance: 30
                },
                transitionDuration: 250
            },
            title: {
                enable: true
            }
        };
    }
}
```

It's rendered in the HTML template with:

```html
<nvd3 [options]="bpOptions" [data]="bpData" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>
```

With ng2-charts, the tooltip only shows when I hover over the data points on the graph.

[image: ng2-charts]

Is it possible to group the data in a tooltip with Chart.js/ng2-charts so it shows both entries for a particular day?

Here's the code used to map the data:

```js
// Get blood pressure readings for the last 30 days
this.bloodPressureService.last30Days().subscribe((bpReadings: any) => {
  bpReadings = bpReadings.body;
  this.bpReadings = bpReadings;

  if (bpReadings.readings.length) {
    this.bpOptions = {
      plugins: {
        legend: { display: true },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: bpReadings.period,
        },
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: false,
        },
        x: {
          beginAtZero: false,
        },
      },
    };
    // this.bpOptions.chart.yAxis.axisLabel = 'Blood Pressure';
    const labels: any = [];
    const systolics: any = [];
    const diastolics: any = [];
    const upperValues: any = [];
    const lowerValues: any = [];
    bpReadings.readings.forEach((item: IBloodPressure) => {
      const timestamp = dayjs(item.timestamp).format('MMM DD');
      labels.push(timestamp);
      systolics.push({
        x: timestamp,
        y: item.systolic,
      });
      diastolics.push({
        x: timestamp,
        y: item.diastolic,
      });
      upperValues.push(item.systolic);
      lowerValues.push(item.diastolic);
    });
    const datasets = [
      {
        data: systolics,
        label: 'Systolic',
      },
      {
        data: diastolics,
        label: 'Diastolic',
      },
    ];
    this.bpData = {
      labels,
      datasets,
    };
    // set y scale to be 10 more than max and min
    this.bpOptions.scales = {
      y: {
        max: Math.max(...upperValues) + 10,
        min: Math.min(...lowerValues) - 10,
      },
    };
  } else {
    this.bpReadings.readings = [];
  }
});
```

It's rendered by the HTML template with:

```html
<canvas
  baseChart
  *ngIf="bpReadings?.readings && bpReadings?.readings?.length"
  height="125"
  [type]="'line'"
  [data]="bpData"
  [options]="bpOptions"
>
</canvas>
```

I'm also curious to know how to pad the dates a bit, so the chart has some padding and the data points aren't at the very ends of the X axis.

I tried the following, which does seem to give me the correct dates. However, the lines don't render after I add it.

```js
this.bpOptions.scales = {
  y: { ... },
  x: {
    min: dayjs(labels[0]).subtract(1, 'day').format('MMM DD'),
    max: dayjs(labels[labels.length - 1]).add(1, 'day').format('MMM DD'),
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add to chart `bpOptions`

```
interaction: {
  mode: 'index',
  intersect: false, // if true, the interaction mode only applies when the mouse position intersects an item on the chart.
},
```

more interactions in docs [interaction modes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#modes)

Comment: Thanks, this works great! I updated my question to include what I tried to pad the x axis.