# Keep reference of array of objects to update in directive too

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello everyone and thanks for the help and for reading my Post.
I have a Service:

```
var itemsMarker = {};
    itemsMarker.items = [];
```

so every time I should update the items of itemsMarkers:
//here I should clean the `itemsMarker.items` before and

```
angular.copy(source, itemsMarker.items);
```

with that Line of code every time the reference of the variable is not lost, so my directive 
`ng-repeat=itemsMarker.items` updates every time the array changes.

But now I do not want to use `angular.copy` because it is slow.

So I tried to replace it these options:

1.- First Option:
`itemsMarker.items.length = 0;
     itemsMarker.items = _.clone(newArraySameStruct);`
Reference is gone. the ng-repeat does not update after the change.

2.- Second option I tried: 
 `itemsMarker.items.length = 0;`
 `itemsMarker.items.push(newArraySameStruct);`

but it adds the array  `newArraySameStruct into 
itemMarker.items[0][newArraySameStruct]`

How can I implement here? 
Regards.

Comment: try with `angular.extend`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for copying we shouldn't include `_.` underscore library. Not a better solution. You can use `angular.extend` or other angular methods. Here you can find more information. [Should I Use Angular.copy() or _.clone()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411754/should-i-use-angular-copy-or-clone)

Comment: seems angular.extend is fast. by now is okay. Should you recommend to build my own copy of objects for a future? Because angular.extend is faster than angular.copy but is slow as well.